# Use pandas element as key in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary:
`fdict={"X":['tf','pytorch','keras'],"Y":['Gym','Scikit']}`
and a dataframe `df` with columns `c1` and `c2`:

1. c1   c2
2. X    pesos
3. Y    long
4. X    Myst

and I want to get:
`'pytorch' in fdict[df['c1']]` as boolian response, in this case it would be `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with lambda function and `get`, output is boolean `Series`:

```
m = df['c1'].apply(lambda x: 'pytorch' in fdict.get(x, None))
print (m)
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: c1, dtype: bool
```

If want test if at least one `True` add [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
m1 = df['c1'].apply(lambda x: 'pytorch' in fdict.get(x, None)).any()
print (m1)
True
```